# stopping CRF++ running and resume its running

Tags: nlp

I 'm using CRF++ in my project running in Ubuntu 12.04 as an Operating System. I have lot of features , so that the training step takes days.

I want to know if it is possible to stop the running of CRF++ for several hours and resume the running from the last iteration (not from the beginning).

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try hibernating the machine? Or can you try to pause the process? And see if it resumes correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try running Crf++ with multi thread. option -p . If you have multiprocessor system , it will speed up your work.